# Is it true that in REST two URLs can never identify the same resource?

Tags: rest, url

I thought that a *single resource* can be identified by *many URLs*.

[From](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hal-discuss/oIARnoKInpM/5FE40uIJAOAJ):

> A resource in a hypermedia API is probably better thought of
>   representing the API response rather than the underlying model
>   instance, as the response is obviously not the same from these two
>   URLs

But above quote suggests that in REST each URL always identifies a *different resource* ( thus two URLs can never identify the *same resource* ). Reason being that a *resource* in a hypermedia API is better thought of as representing the *API response* rather than the *underlying model instance*, and considering that *API responses* from different URLs are definitely not identical, the conclusion is that two URLs can never identify the same *resource*.

Would you agree that in REST a *resource* should be thought of as representing the *API response* and as such two URLs can never identify the same *resource*?

Thank you

Comment: When you read something somewhere,start quoting the source.Or you sound like Fox news "some people say".

Comment: @mpm: I've included the quote and a source. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr no - two URIs can refer to the same resource**

There is nothing wrong with a 'resource' being represented by multiple URIs, or URIs 'linking' to a virtual resource that does not exist until a user GETs it and the server calculates what that value should be.

example, `/schools/5/pupils/thecoshman` would be the same as `/pupils/thecoshman`, it's me, it's just the first UIR lets you know (well, presume) I am in 'school 5'. Ideally though, the URI should be returned as the shortest form, so I'd say the second one should represent me.

Why would you get that longer one? Well, what if you called `/schools/5/pupils`? That would return a list of 'pupils' in that school (though probably as more than just a list like this).

```
/schools/5/pupils/thecoshman
/schools/5/pupils/bckpwrld
```

Though as I said above, you should probably link to the shortest (in terms of hierarchy) URI for the resource, so drop the '/schools/5' prefix. The users *just* got this data from /schools/5/pupils/.

Comment: So if needed, I can have SAME resource being identified by two very different URLs, for example by http://school/pupils/bckwrld and http://home/Edvard?

Comment: Sure. Though, not sure quite oh a 'pupil' and 'home' can be the same... also, you should favour plurals.

Comment: "not sure quite oh a 'pupil' and 'home' can be the same." Why should 'pupil' and 'home' be the same? The two Urls identify me as a resource, where in school I go by the name bckpwrld ( not true btw :) ) and at home I go by the name Edvard.

Comment: oh, well there we go, your URIs were not clear. I thought 'homes' would have been, you know, homes. so you are saying more like `/schools/5/pupils/bckpwrld` would be the same 'resource' as `/people/Edvard`.

Comment: Yes, though I find my URLs to also be clear :). Anyways, thank you for your help

Comment: well no, because you had `/home/` which would imply 'Edvard' **IS A** home.

Comment: uhm, I didn't know it implies "is" relationship. thanx

Comment: because URI's hierarchical, so you saying that 'Edvard' fits within the grouping of 'home', and why would it if it were not a home itself?